# lambda duration spike when new cloudwatch log stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

#### The problem

I have an aws lambda that runs by ~2ms of runtime duration. Each time a new cloudwatch log stream in that lambda's log-group is created, the first run of that lambda takes ~15K ms (x7500 factor).

I'm looking for a way to make the lambda permanently run in ~2ms, and avoid those duration spikes completely.

#### Investigation details

1. I thought that it is related to lambda warmup on behind-the-scenes container allocation, so I added a event-bridge trigger by constant rate of every 3 minutes to that lambda. Also, I allocated provisioned-concurrency for that lambda. But it didn't solve the issue.
2. I have another lambda, both are using the same code but running in a different flow and it doesn't happen to it.
3. Note that currently there is no external traffic, only the event-bridge triggering which has a controlled rate.
4. If it's relevant: I'm using python3.7 with NLTK lib in both lambdas but the delayed one is using wordnet's lemmatization (statically defined as recommended [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/static-initialization.html)).

Comment: You mean it runs 15 seconds even with provisioned concurrency?

Comment: @marcin yes (provisioned concurrency allocated to 2)

Comment: This must be something wrong with your function, which code is not shown. Maybe it depends on some API calls?  Its very unlikely that provisioned-concurency would lead to 15 s delays.

Comment: @marcin the only difference between my two lambda functions is that the delayed one is calling:

```python
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer;
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer() # statically initiallized;

lemmatizer.lemmatize(input_word, "v")
```

I've looked at the NLTK code as it is open-source and no external API call is done within this function (relying only on local data and internal, even quite simple. logic)